# Use latest package for installation in yocto?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

I have to install kubernetes v1.17.6. In my meta-test layer, I created a new recipe `kubernetes_git.bb` inside `recipes-containers/kubernetes` directory. I am working on zeus branch and as the poky layer has ****go**** version 1.12, I get an error as

> kubernetes v1.17.6 requires **go** version 1.13+

**Go** directory inside `poky/meta/recipes-devtools` contains a lot of contents so I first thought of just copying and replacing the v1.12 to v1.14, but this is not simple as it looks. The earlier problem disappeared but as there are a lot of other recipes which were dependent on the go version 1.12, I got other errors because of that, so I could not just replace that.

Then, in meta-test layer, I created a new folder meta-devtools and copied the **go** v1.14 into it. I am pretty sure this is not an appropriate way to do this because I am again getting the first error of requiring newer version of **go**.
Is it possible to point kubernetes in meta-test layer to use **go** version v1.14 or is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Take go recipe, inc and patch files from dunfell (1.14.1) and see if it helps. Put all those in your layer. Also... dunfell is LTS, then jump from zeus to dunfell shouldn't be that big so maybe it's worth just upgrading to dunfell?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to your `local.conf`

```
PREFERRED_VERSION_kubernetes = "1.14"
```

alternatively, change the priority of your layer to higher than `5` (priority of `poky/meta` layer).

Comment: I think there's a slight misunderstanding, I do not want kubernetes version 1.14, rather kubernetes version 1.17.6 requires "go" version 1.13+

Comment: and the most important thing is that only kubernetes v1.17.6 requires go version 1.13+, most of the other recipes require older version of go

Comment: Set priority for `go` package and build your `kubernetes` version.

Comment: I did that and its working and I had to set the priority not only for go but for go-native, go-runtime and so on, earlier I had only set for go, and also there is a variable GOVERSION which poky has intialized to 1.12%, so instead of setting all those priorities, increasing this to 1.14% worked for me.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk - does it matter where do I place it in the local.conf file?